# Parsing a Hadoop version string with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, numeric-data

we have this CLI syntax

```
hdp-select | grep hadoop-client
hadoop-client - 2.6.4.0-91
```

the final goal is to get the number as example:

```
2640
```

we capture the last number & remove the `-` and remove the `.`

so I did

```
 hdp-select | grep hadoop-client | awk '{print $3}' | sed s'/-/ /g' | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/\.//g'
 2640
```

but this is ugly solution

I will happy to know other elegant solution

Comment: It’s not really a floating point number that you’re starting from; perhaps a “version string”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sed

```
hdp-select | sed '/^hadoop-client - /!d;s///;s/-.*//;s/\.//g'
```

Comment: What’s the s///; do?

Comment: The empty regular express will re-use the previous one to remove the string "hadoop-client - "

Comment: Maybe: `sed '/^.*hadoop-client - \([0-9.]\+\)-.*/{s//\1/;s/\.//g}'`

Answer (score 3):

Optimized solution with single **`awk`** program:

```
hdp-select | awk -F'-' '/^hadoop-client/{ gsub(/[[:space:].]+/, "", $3); print $3; exit }'
```

The output:

```
2640
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that in bash:

```
input='2.6.4.0-91'
input=${input%-*}
input=${input//./}
echo "$input"
2640
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk: Use `-`, `.` and space as separators and print columns 5 to 8.

```
hdp-select | awk -F '[-. ]' '/hadoop-client/ {print $5$6$7$8}'
```

Output:

```
2640
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`, arguably simpler than the other (two commands vs three):

```
hdp-select | sed -n 's/hadoop-client - \(.*\)-.*/\1/;s/\.//gp'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column tool from the util-linux package:

```
column -t -s . -o '' <<'eof'
1.0.0
eof
```

Or:

```
echo 1.0.0 | column -t -s . -o ''
```

Result:

```
100
```

Comment: This is only the last step, ewuivalent to only: `| sed 's/\.//g'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
input="hadoop-client - 2.6.4.0-91"
if [[ "$input" =~ ([0-9\.]+) ]] ; then
    value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
    value=${value//./}
    echo "Matched '$value'"
else
    echo "Unparseable"
fi
```

It's not one line, but that's an advantage for me. It's readable, and uses only the tools it needs to - a regular expression to extract the digits of the version number, and then a replacement to strip out the '.' characters. Additionally, it gives a basic form of validation that what was given is what was expected - if you wanted to be more cautious, you'd throw in `hadoop-client\ -\` before the bracket in the regex to check that the input really is what you think it should be.

Relies on regular expressions in bash, but as they've been around since bash version 3 (2004), that's probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is suitable for someone who knows regular expressions and does not know `sed` or `awk`.

`expr` and `tr` come from "GNU Core Utilities". Unfortunately, `expr` uses *basic regular expression* and each regular expression is anchored with `^`.

```
expr "$(hdp-select)" : '.*oop-client - \(\([0-9]\+\.\?\)\+\)-[0-9]\+' | tr -d '.'
```

**Result:**

```
2640
```

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to do it directly in the shell (bash):

```
$ re='hadoop-client - ([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)-'
$ a=$(hdp-select)
$ (IFS='' ; [[ $a =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}" )
2640
```

If you are limited to older shells, use a similar regex with `expr`:

```
$ expr "$(hdp-select)" : '.*client - \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)-.*' | sed 's/\.//g'
```